# SAPUI5 Lifecycle

Tags: sapui5, lifecycle

When do the lifecycle methods occur in SAPUI5? I have two views, let's call them A and B. By clicking a button in A, I use `navTo()` to go to the view B. The first time I do this, the `onInit()` function gets called, but if I go back to view A  and back to B again, the function does NOT get called again.

How can I make it so that I call `onInit()` again? How can I make it so that navigating from B to A deletes the B view?

I see that data remains after going back and forth between A and B and I think it's because B isn't destroyed. They both have their own controllers and B has a fragment in it's xml view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is the designed behaviour. You can use **patternMatched** event of the router to do things every time user navigates to the particular view. Normally, the event handler can be attached to the router in your controller **onInit** event. The code could look like this:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("<sufficient route name>").attachPatternMatched(this.yourPatternMatchedHandler, this);
```

Among others you can find a sample [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/master-detail/webapp/test/mockServer.html#/Objects/ObjectID_1)